# How to disable the warning when saving names that begin with a dot?

Tags: macos

I get a warning when I try to save a dotfile. The warning message is:

[image]

[image]

How can I disable this?

Comment: http://imgur.com/YDFzpoW

Comment: afaik you can't. manually rename them with `$mv paco.rtf .paco.rtf`(in a terminal)

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily disable that on OS X. You can easily set up a folder action to rename files you save once they hit the filesystem. It's clunky, but better than renaming things by hand.

Comment: Just pressing Enter on that dialog is less hassle and requires no renaming than a folder action which requires you to move the dotfile after its creation?

Comment: @grgarside Yes - but it doesn't disable the warning. It's a bad workaround - but if you do this dozens of times a day, automating a workaround is still viable. Hard to tell - I'm guessing the OP was hoping for a quick patch.